# Transition to another View Controller from UITableViewCell Freezes the app - iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios11, xcode9

I have a UITableView with various posts, that the user can comment on. Once the user taps on the comment button in the cell, the comments view controller is loaded, and viewwillappear is called but before presenting the view, the app freezes. I am making an API call to fetch the comments in viewDidLoad and reloading the table once the API call is finished. I am not able to figure where iOS 11 is doing things differently. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You have any error massage ?

Comment: No error messages. Just freezes the app.

Comment: Add some code, especially what you do in viewWillAppear / viewDidLoad

Comment: @rdurand, yes, that's where the issue seems to have been. I have answered the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to be with the Navigation Controller, like most issues on iOS 11 transition.

I was setting the right bar buttons for the viewcontroller in viewDidLoad. Commented that line of code and moved it to viewDidAppear and the app wasn't freezing.

***But*** this gave rise to another freeze when user taps on the back button. So I recreated the segues in XCode 9 and ***did not*** set the right bar buttons on the navigation item at all. This seemed to fix the issue and there isn't any freeze right now. Hope this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Call API in background thread

```
let dispatchTime: DispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime, execute: {
            DispatchQueue.main.async{

               //Call API function here
            }
        })
```